# Full browser flash works in Safari 5 but not Firefox 3.6

Tags: javascript, flash, debugging, cross-browser, swfobject

Can anyone give me a clue as to why this markup works fine in Safari, but not in Firefox?

This should load an ugly blue placeholder (which I get in safari) but in Firefox, swfobject just gives me the alternative content.

http://www.johndierks.com/stackoverflow/preloader.html

Thanks for your help.

Here's the code for reference, which I got from SwfObject's google code site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SWFObject 2 full browser flash</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            html, body, #content    { height:100%; }
            body                    { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
            #altContent             { /* style alt content */ }
        </style>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        swfobject.registerObject("myId", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf");
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">  
            <object id="myId" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%">
                <param name="movie" value="ccholidaypreloader.swf" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="test6.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
                <!--<![endif]-->
                <div id="altContent">

                    <h1>Alternative content</h1>
                    <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
                </div>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

404 not found http://www.johndierks.com/stackoverflow/test6.swf
(From Firebug)

Comment: @John. No problem. With firebug, turn "Show Network Errors" on, it's really handy for development/debugging.. It shows you right aways anything that fails with 404, very handy for typos, etc